# Evaluating $\int \frac{x^m}{(x - a)^n}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there a nice easy way to evaluate either

$$\int \frac{x^m}{(x - a)^n}dx$$

or

$$\int \frac{(x - b)^m}{(x - a)^n}dx$$

Where $m, n$ are integers? For the first the best I can come up with is turning $x^m$ into $x^m - a^m + a^m$, factoring & continually reducing things, & the second I'd expand x - b & use the first method, but these can get messy!

Comment: Try putting  $x-a=y$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: $x^m$ is now $(y+a)^m$.

Comment: @Inceptio which can now be expanded via the binomial theorem, so the integrand is of the form $y^{m-n} + c_1 y^{m-n-1} + \ldots + c_m y^{-n}$

Comment: @Stahl: Yes, now I get it..

Comment: Great, I even thought of it but didn't finish my thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In fact expanding the binomial expansion is nearly the only approach for evaluating $\int\dfrac{x^m}{(x-a)^n}dx$ and $\int\dfrac{(x-b)^m}{(x-a)^n}dx$ .

For $\int\dfrac{x^m}{(x-a)^n}dx$ ,

When $m$ is a positive integer,

$\int\dfrac{x^m}{(x-a)^n}dx=\int\dfrac{(x-a+a)^m}{(x-a)^n}dx=\int\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^mC_k^ma^{m-k}(x-a)^k}{(x-a)^n}dx=\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^mC_k^ma^{m-k}(x-a)^{k-n}~dx$

Then integrate it termwisely. Beware whether the $\ln(x-a)$ term exist.

When $n$ is a negative integer,

$\int\dfrac{x^m}{(x-a)^n}dx=\int x^m(x-a)^{-n}~dx=\int x^m\sum\limits_{k=0}^{-n}C_k^{-n}(-1)^ka^kx^{-n-k}~dx=\int\sum\limits_{k=0}^{-n}C_k^{-n}(-1)^ka^kx^{m-n-k}~dx$

Then integrate it termwisely. Beware whether the $\ln x$ term exist.

Similar on $\int\dfrac{(x-b)^m}{(x-a)^n}dx$ .