# solving or integration of $y'=-\left(\frac{x-a}{x+b}\right)^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to integrate following expression

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\left(\frac{x-a}{x+b}\right)^{-n}$

Mathematica gives

[image]

I want to know the process!

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423433/631742

Comment: @TeM Thank you, I‘ve learned something new from your comment